# Node.js test script not executing with Appium for iOS

Tags: node.js, appium, appium-ios, appium-desktop

I've successfully integrated `Appium` desktop app and works fine by following this tutorial:
http://latestsoftwaretestingnews.com/mobiletesting/appium-ios-testing-with-node-js-step-by-step-guide/

**main.js**

```
describe ('Simple cases', function (){
      before (function (){
        this.timeout(50000);
        return client.init();
      });
      describe('test-app-addition', function (){
        it('add-3-3', function(){
          return client.element('~IntegerA')
          .setValue ('3')
          .elementByAccessibilityId ('~IntegerB')
          .setValue('3')
          .click('~ComputeSumButton')
          .element('~Answer')
          .getText()
          .then(function (text){
            expect(text).to.equal('6');
          });
        });
      });
      after(function(){
        return client.end();
      });
    });
```

but on executing `$npm run native` command getting an error. Refer screenshot

[image]

Appreciate your help and suggestions!

Thanks

Comment: Based on the error it sounds like your missing a capabilities object. Appium has an example test package here to compare with https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/sample-code/javascript-wd/test/helpers/config.js